# Excel Rank vs SQL Rank

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have the following dilemma.

I need to `rank` data in Excel, the same way I rank it in SQL as can be seen below:

```
declare @table table
(id int identity primary key , batchid int)

insert into @table (batchid) select 10
insert into @table (batchid) select 35
insert into @table (batchid) select 35
insert into @table (batchid) select 35
insert into @table (batchid) select 8
insert into @table (batchid) select 21
insert into @table (batchid) select 10
insert into @table (batchid) select 11
insert into @table (batchid) select 4
insert into @table (batchid) select 10
insert into @table (batchid) select 11
insert into @table (batchid) select 4
insert into @table (batchid) select 21
insert into @table (batchid) select 8
insert into @table (batchid) select 21
insert into @table (batchid) select 8
insert into @table (batchid) select 21
insert into @table (batchid) select 4
insert into @table (batchid) select 21
insert into @table (batchid) select 10
insert into @table (batchid) select 21
insert into @table (batchid) select 11
insert into @table (batchid) select 21
insert into @table (batchid) select 8
insert into @table (batchid) select 21
insert into @table (batchid) select 10
insert into @table (batchid) select 21
insert into @table (batchid) select 10
insert into @table (batchid) select 21

select
batchid
,   rank() over (partition by batchid order by id)  [RANK]
from    @table
```

I looked at a lot of **YouTube** videos and tutorials of how to `rank` in **Excel**, however I do not see the option to `partition by` that `rank` as can be seen in code above.

See below results of the above script:

[image]

What formula can I use in Excel to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy with simple formula:

[image]

In cell `B1` you enter initial value `1`. Then, in `B2` you enter a formula:

```
=IF(A1=A2,B1+1,1)
```

Then drag it all the way down.

Comment: This is the most simple formula that solves the problem. Thanks @Michal!

Answer (score 0):

Check [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e). Example from, [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4319-excel-rank-by-group.html):

> Select a blank cell next to the data, C2 for instance, type this
>   formula,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$11=A2)*(B2<$B$2:$B$11))+1
```

> then drag autofill handle down to apply this formula to the cells you need.
>
> In the formula, A2:A11 is the range containing the group values, A2 is
>   the first cell in the list of group values, B2 is the first cell in
>   the list which needed to rank, B2:B11 is the list that contains values
>   needed to rank.

[image]